# Pass command line option to npm install in gradle node plugin

Tags: gradle-node-plugin

Using the gradle node plugin **com.github.node-gradle.node**, how do I pass a command line option to the NpmInstallTask?

Background: For security reasons, I want to pass "--ignore-scripts".

Comment: This seems like a good feature to request from the project!

Answer (score 0):

The `npmCommand` in `NpmInstallTask` inherited from [NpmTask](https://github.com/node-gradle/gradle-node-plugin/blob/d15f7eefd073c98d474d2b0fe40bd85437ac9c8c/src/main/kotlin/com/github/gradle/node/npm/task/NpmTask.kt#L31) is a listProperty

If you set that to `["install", "--ignore-scripts"]` it should be correctly passed

Answer (score 0):

You can use following snippet ([as documented here](https://github.com/node-gradle/gradle-node-plugin/blob/master/docs/faq.md#how-do-i-set-log-level-for-npm-install-task)):

```
npmInstall.args = ['--ignore-scripts']
```